# Javascript > Vue.js How to transfer javascript to vue.js script

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

As I hope to use selected textarea, I found Javascript, but I don't know how to use it as the vue script

```
 $(document).ready(function () {$(".editorHTMLDIV").hide();}); 
 function convertToHTML() { 
   $('.editorHTMLDIV').text($('.editorDIV').html());
   $('.editorHTMLDIV').show(); 
   $('.editorDIV').hide();
```

I want to use this Javascript as Vue script like

```
<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>
<script> 
I wanna know this area
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide a piece of your HTML code? Also, when do you want the `convertToHTML` function to be called?

Comment: jQuery is a DOM manipulation library, Vue is a template binding framework. They are very different concepts. You have taken the most basic form of a piece of jQuery logic and asked how to translate it to Vue. There is no real direct translation, you just need to learn some Vue.

Comment: Thx all comments, I just started studying Vue.js I wish I could do like yours :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
<template>
    <div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "name-of-your-component",
    data: function () {
        return { };
    },
    methods: {
        convertToHTML: function () {
            $('.editorHTMLDIV').text($('.editorDIV').html());
            $('.editorHTMLDIV').show(); 
            $('.editorDIV').hide();
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        $(".editorHTMLDIV").hide();
    },
}
</script>
```

However, the above script is just a sample and it probably will not meet your specification requirements (you have not mentioned any in your question).

Likewise, I would strongly recommend that you study the Vue lifecycle which can be found [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) and also, the Vue library in general.

Also, the jQuery library and the Vue framework are two completely different aspects. You cannot just translate code from one to another.